# Determining the Right Vector of an object with a Rotation Matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, glm-math

I am attempting to locate get Right vector of an object that I have already computed a Rotation Matrix for, so that it can strafe in 3d space. Thus far I have gotten

```
    glm::quat gOrientation2 = glm::quat(glm::radians(entity.orientation));
    glm::mat4 RotationMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(gOrientation2);
    entup = glm::vec3(RotationMatrix[1][0], RotationMatrix[1][1], RotationMatrix[1][2]);
    entforward = glm::vec3(RotationMatrix[2][0], RotationMatrix[2][1], RotationMatrix[2][2]);
    entright = glm::vec3(RotationMatrix[0][0], RotationMatrix[0][1], RotationMatrix[0][2]) ;
```

After staring at it some more, I'm posting the handler for it moving left and right, pondering if the issue may actually lie within there.

```
//the (10, -10, 10) vec3 is just a generic speed that moves 
//it forward then multiplied by dir.
if (glfwGetKey(65) == GLFW_PRESS){
    if(entity.player == 1)
        entity.position += glm::vec3(10,-10,10)*entright*deltaTime;
}
if (glfwGetKey(68) == GLFW_PRESS){
    if(entity.player == 1)
        entity.position -= glm::vec3(10,-10,10)*entright*deltaTime;
}
```

This has been working fine, as long as I only pitch and yaw. As soon as the object attempts to roll, it's right vector faces 90 degrees from where it should. I know I could extract the first row of the RotationMatrix to also acquire the Right, but that achieves the same results as the above code.

Picture to illustrate issue 
http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/5046/directionexample.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The order you are multiplying your quaternions is confusing. Try changing

```
glm::quat gOrientation2 = rY*rX*rZ;
```

to

```
glm::quat gOrientation2 = (rX*rY)*rZ
```

as you say there is no point in doing the cross product; just grab the right vector out of the rotation matrix directly.

This is not the most efficient or succinct way to use glm to convert euler angles to a quaternion and then a rotation matrix. glm has built in functions for this; check the documentation.

Comment: Edited it to just be: glm::quat gOrientation2 = glm::quat(glm::radians(entity.orientation));

Comment: No, it still strafes in the wrong direction. I'll put up an image with some arrows to illustrate.